# Configure Jenkins PMD to promote status from Stable to Failed

Tags: jenkins, static-analysis, pmd

I want to configure my Jenkins server to flag a build as unstable if PMD violations are found and then if the violations are not fixed in a subsequent build, the build should be flagged as failed.

I've tried configuring the PMD plugin thresholds on this, but its either unstable or failed - i can't get it move from state to state. I thought I had seen this behavior from Jenkins/PMD on another project, but I may have been mistaken, is there some combination of plugins that could let me do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like this is possible with the PMD plugin, unfortunately. As mentioned in the question, it's possible to mark a build as failed or unstable using the thresholds, but this doesn't have any memory from build to build.

The closest thing to what you want is that you can mark a build as failed or unstable by calculating the difference in number of warnings between the current and previous build (tick "Compute new warnings (based on reference build)" in the project configuration). E.g. mark as unstable if there are *x* more violations than the previous build. However, what you want is to mark it as failed if there are 0 or more violations, but only in the case that there are violations in the first place - this would likely have the undesired effect of causing all builds to fail if there is even one violation.

Perhaps it's worth [requesting this feature](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PMD+Plugin) with the developer?

Comment: I'll have a crack at implementing this myself and if I get nowhere request it from the developer.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by integrating `maven`, `ant`, `PMD` build tools.

After the successful integration, once the build is completed, we can check the violation count returned by the PMD against the threshold we passed as an argument to the ant build. If the violation count exceeds the threshold, then mark the build as Failed.

This settings can be integrated to Jenkins (Continuous Integration and Deployment).